# How to override the default input field value using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using python and selenium to scrape this [website](https://www.edmunds.com/cars-for-sale-by-owner/) and I need to override the default value in the zipcode field. I have used the `.clear()` method and then tried sending my own values using the `send_keys()` function but the default zipcode still remains in the input field. Does anyone have any idea how to go around this? Below is my code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager import driver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
radius = int(input("Enter the radius: "))
zipcode = int(input("Enter your zipcode"))

url = f'https://www.edmunds.com/cars-for-sale-by-owner/'

options = Options()
options.headless = False
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get(url)
browser.set_page_load_timeout(15)

zipcode_form = browser.find_element_by_name('zip')
zipcode_form.clear() #This is meant to clear the default value in the zipcode field
zipcode_form.send_keys(str(zipcode)) #This is enter the zipcode value I provided in the zipcode field
zipcode_form.send_keys(Keys.RETURN) #I did this because there is no button to click after filling the zipcode form on the website and pressing enter works instead

... # The rest of my code which extracts the information I want
```

I just started learning selenium pardon me if I made any silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple ways of doing this. One is using Javascript Executor defined below. "value" contains zip to be entered.

```
element = driver.find_element_by_name('zip')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value='" + value + "';", element)
```

Comment: Hi Kumar, thanks for the response.

Tried the code snippet you suggested, the problem still persist.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest finding the driver element by ID, as it's unique to that element:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('zip').clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to find solution to the problem using [WebDriverWait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) [ActionChains](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html) classes in selenium. The code is below:

```
 WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 'zip')))
 zipcode_form = driver.find_element_by_name('zip')
```

I used the `WebDriverWait` class to tell selenium to explicitly wait until the zipcode input form is clickable on the webpage before it attempts to find it. i.e until the webpage loads to an extent I can interact with the zipcode input form. After that I now instantiated the ActionChains class and called some methods on it to clear the default value in the zipcode form and fill it with the one I specified. Just like this:

```
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(zipcode_form).click(zipcode_form).click(zipcode_form).send_keys(Keys.DELETE).send_keys(str(zipcode)).perform()
```

The `move_to_element` method tells selenium to move to the element I specified, in my case it is the zipcode input form. I used the `click` method twice because the ActionChains method does not have the `clear` method to clear the default value of an input field. Using the `click` method twice imitates a user clicking on an input field twice thereby highlighting whatever text is in it twice. I then called the `send_keys` method and passed in the `Keys.DELETE` value to delete whatever text has been highlighted. I then called the `send_keys` method again this time passing the value of my zipcode. The `perform` method tells selenium to perform the events in the order they have been written. In our case, selenium will perform the `move_to_element` event first before performing the `click` event and then it goes on like that until the last `send_keys` event.

I really apppreciate Kumar and Adrian who tried to help me figure it out.